# Powershell Functions using ToolStripMenuItem work in an unintended way

Tags: winforms, powershell

Something that I can not understand while creating a GUI with PowerShell

Reappearance:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function Build-MainForm2 () {
    $form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

    # MenuStrip
    $menuStrip = New-Object Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
    $menuStrip.Dock = 'Top'

    # MenuStripItem
    $msFile = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem  -ArgumentList 'File'

    # Build Form
    $menuStrip.Items.Add($msFile)
    $form.Controls.Add($menuStrip)

    return $form
}

$mainForm = Build-MainForm2
$mainForm.showDialog()
```

When I run this script PowerShell ISE show me error like this

```
[System.Object[]]에 이름이 'showDialog'인 메서드가 없으므로 메서드를 호출하지 못했습니다.
위치 D:\ProgramData\stgr\TWT\win\TwT\src\wtf.ps1:21 문자:25
+     $mainForm.showDialog <<<< ()
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (showDialog:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

What it means is that there is no method

---

But when I comment out the 15th line

`$menuStrip.Items.Add($msFile)` -> `#$menuStrip.Items.Add($msFile)`

The script works fine
[image: works fine]

---

Go back to the beginning. I was wondering about the return value of Build-MainForm2, and when I tried to print out the value, it was an array with 0 and a Form instance.

`(0, [System.Windows.Forms.Form])`

After all, you can make the script work by changing the final code as follows:

`$mainForm[1].showDialog()`

But I still do not know why the return value was converted to this array.
I wonder if there is a neat solution to this.

---

Enviroment: PowerShell ISE 2.0 (Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add` method on `Items` returns an integer.  You are not handling this, so it's getting inserted into your variable as an array item.

You can fix this by redirecting that output:

```
$null = $menuStrip.Items.Add($msFile)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
By the way, the return of PowerShell functions seems to be unclear.
If the syntax in the function does not know for sure whether it has a return value like this, is it necessary to attach `$ null =` before every line?

Comment: @SemteulGaram It takes some getting used to, but think of everything the comes out of a function as its return.  The `return` keyword here is a control construct to exit a function while also outputting something.  If a function has more than one return, the results are an array.  It's only necessary to redirect output if you don't want it in the result of your function, this can be achieved in three ways: `$null =`, `> $null`, or `| Out-Null`.

Comment: I found one more thing; `[Void]` before the line